# Neo4j in Javascript: Parameters not put in to query

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher

I'm running into trouble when using the [neo4j plugin of thingdom](https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j). It seems like the plugin is not able to recognize *{mlabel}* and *{mdata}* as placeholders. Code and error follows.

Thank you very much!

```
var query = [
    'CREATE (p:{mlabel} {{mdata}})',
    'RETURN p'
].join('\n');

var params = {
    mlabel : 'person',
    mdata  : {
        name: 'Pete',
        surname: 'Strutton',
        age: 35
    }
};

this.db.query(query, params, function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return result;
});
```

> ```
> Error: Invalid input '{': expected whitespace or a label name (line 1, column 11)
> "CREATE (p:{mlabel} {{mdata}})"
>            ^
>     at exports.adjustError (C:\Spree Github Repository\Phone\express\SpreeRouter
> \node_modules\neo4j\lib\util.js:71:15)
>     at __$GraphDatabase_prototype_query__20 (C:\Spree Github Repository\Phone\ex
> press\SpreeRouter\node_modules\neo4j\lib\GraphDatabase.js:942:26)
>     at C:\Spree Github Repository\Phone\express\SpreeRouter\node_modules\neo4j\l
> ib\GraphDatabase.js:2:6247
>     at Object.__g.trampoline.flush (C:\Spree Github Repository\Phone\express\Spr
> eeRouter\node_modules\neo4j\lib\Node.js:2:3552)
>     at Request.___ [as _callback] (C:\Spree Github Repository\Phone\express\Spre
> eRouter\node_modules\neo4j\lib\GraphDatabase.js:2:5602)
>     at Request.self.callback (C:\Spree Github Repository\Phone\express\SpreeRout
> er\node_modules\neo4j\node_modules\request\request.js:372:22)
>     at Request.emit (events.js:98:17)
>     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Spree Github Repository\Phone\express\SpreeRouter
> \node_modules\neo4j\node_modules\request\request.js:1317:14)
>     at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
>     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Spree Github Repository\Phone\express\Spr
> eeRouter\node_modules\neo4j\node_modules\request\request.js:1265:12)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

You cannot parametrize your query-selectors anywhere. It is only possible on data that you put into your query. The above wouldn't work, but following query would:

```
var query = [
    'CREATE (p:LABEL {mdata})',
    'RETURN p'
].join('\n').replace('LABEL', label);

var params = {
    mdata  : data
};

this.db.query(query, params, function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(results);
    return results[0];
});
```